# vectorize random failure of a graph in R

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

I have the following function that I intend to run on a large scale with 10000 random networks.

```
m.ci.fail<-function(graph){
    fail <- function(net) {
      vids<-sample(V(net),1)
      net <- delete.vertices(net,vids)
      return(net)
    }
    compsize <- function(net,graph) {
      b <- clusters(graph) 
      c <- clusters(net) 
      S <- max(c$csize)/max(b$csize)
      return(S)
    }
    nodes<-1:vcount(graph)
    R<-10000
    cpmat<-matrix(nrow=length(nodes), ncol=R)
    for(i in 1:R){
      gr<-rewire(graph,mode="simple",niter=10000)
      E(gr)$weight<-E(graph)$weight 
      grr<-gr
      E(grr)$weight<-E(graph)$weight
      cp<-numeric(length(nodes))

      for(t in 1:(length(nodes)-1)){
        gr<-fail(gr)
        grcp<-compsize(gr,grr)
        cp[t]<-grcp
      }
    cpmat[,i]<-cp
    }
return(cpmat)
}
```

EDIT: I'm trying to create a randomly re-sampled distribution based on the original graph so I can get a confidence interval and later compare the range of random failures to centrality-based sequential deletions. Testing it as it is took hours with a graph of small size (30 nodes). I figure that if I could find a way to vectorize the random failure function this would be faster. I'm trying to vectorize the two 'for' loops but the fail function is making it a pain. Any suggestion on how I can do that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Which part is slow?

Comment: I guess it's the 2 for loops in the function. I've seen vectorizing functions like apply or mapply before. haven't been able to adapt this one to it. hoped to find some help here.

Comment: How about actually measuring it?

Comment: Sorry @Gabor Casrdi. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html#measure-perf

Comment: @GaborCsardi, Oh sorry, ha. No I haven't measured the time of each function with lineprof(). I measured the overall and the fail() function time with system.time(). it's not the fail() it's the 2 loops that increases time of processing bc it processes one number at a time instead of vectors. I will edit the question again with times from system.time as soon as I can.